# Powershell retry logic script review

Tags: powershell

My requirement is if the $R count is gt 0, then I want to pause for 5 secs then again execute $R and check the count, like this I want to retry for 5 times, after 5 attempts if I still see $R count gt 0  then throw an error.
if $R count eq 0 then the script should come out from the loop without any retry.

I had tried my best as below but error handling is not happening, can someone guide me here..!

```
[int]$retry = 0

do 
{
  $Q = "exec ('DBCC opentran (TestDB)with tableresults')"
  $R = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "TESTSERVER" -Database "TESTDB" -Query $Q

  $count = $R.count
  Write-Host " count is $count" -ForegroundColor Yellow

  if ($count -gt 0)
  {
    $retry = $retry + 1

    Write-Host "retry count is  $retry"

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    if ($retry -gt 5)
    {
      Write-Error "All the retry are finished..!"
    } 
  }
  else 
  {
    write-host "There are no open transactions !"
  }
} 
while ($count -gt 0)
```

Comment: I re-formatted your post slightly and removed something that looked like it had been inserted by the editor by accident, please review to make sure I didn't mess with your code (beyond indentation/formatting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you never break out of the loop.

`Write-Error` does exactly what it says - it writes an error back to the caller - but it doesn't halt execution of the running code/script/function/cmdlet.

You can either set the `$ErrorActionPreference` variable to `Stop`:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
```

If you subsequently run your code again, you'll find that the code now `Stop`s execution as soon as an error is thrown.

But your code shouldn't depend on a preference variable to work correctly, so the real solution here is to *make sure you **break** out of the loop* on error:

```
    if ($retry -gt 5)
    {
      Write-Error "All the retry are finished..!"
      break          # this will stop the do-while loop
    }
```

Comment: Thank you it helped me
I have another question, will post it separately